# WMI/CIM: Unable to access class

Tags: powershell, wmi, cim

I have a non-standard WMI namespace/class I'm trying to access, but am unable to by conventional means.  I can see the class when I use the `-List` parameter, and can assign/access the class when using `-List | Where-Object Name -eq 'Class'`, but am unable to access it via `Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT\Novadigm' -Class 'NVD_Agent'` (returns nothing)

Works:

```
PS C:\> GWMI -Namespace 'ROOT\Novadigm' -List | ? Name -eq NVD_Agent


  Namespace: ROOT\Novadigm

Name          Methods                 Properties
----          -------                 ----------
NVD_Agent     {AddInstance, Del...    {}


PS C:\> Get-CimClass -ClassName 'NVD_Agent' -Namespace 'ROOT\Novadigm'


  Namespace: ROOT/Novadigm

CimClassName  CimClassMethods         CimClassProperties
----          -------                 ----------
NVD_Agent     {AddInstance, Del...    {}
```

Nada:

```
PS C:\> GWMI -Namespace 'ROOT\Novadigm' -Class 'NVD_Agent'
PS C:\>
PS C:\> Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'ROOT\Novadigm' -Class 'NVD_Agent'
PS C:\>
```

Question: Why is this happening?  How can I get it to work by using standard syntax without passing it through `Where-Object`?

Comment: Are there any instances of it to retrieve? I'm not super familiar with custom WMI classes, but it can be defined as a class without having any instances of it created right?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I'm unable to access the default CIM classes either except by the working method in my example.